# Calculator App - strange error: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' when trying to update display

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm relatively new to Objective-C, so I'm not 100% about everything I'm coding. However, I'm tackling my errors as they happen, and I am getting a run-time error that I'm not sure how to fix. The error claims that an 'unrecognized selector [was] sent to instance.'

```
- (IBAction) equalsPressed{
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
    if (self.brain.operationIsPicked) {
       [self.brain pushOperand: [self.display.text doubleValue]]; 
       double result = [self.brain performOperation: self.brain.operation];
       // The line below this 
       self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%g", result];
    }
}
```

I'm doing the Calculator app taught by the Stanford professor whose course is posted in iTunes U. However, I edited it to not include an enterPressed command and instead use an altered and more user-friendly 'equalsPressed.' After equalsPressed is finished (meaning when I click the equals sign on the calculator), the error is displayed. Might anyone know what is causing this problem? I already found someone else who has an error very similar to this one, but occurring in a slightly different place. Here are the other code snippets that could help elucidate the problem.

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain

@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;
@synthesize operandStackIsEmpty = _operandStackIsEmpty;
@synthesize operationIsPicked = _operationIsPicked;
@synthesize operation = _operation;

- (NSMutableArray *) operandStack {
    if (!_operandStack) {
        _operandStack =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _operandStackIsEmpty = YES;
        _operationIsPicked = NO;
    }
    return _operandStack;
}

- (void) resetStack {
    [self.operandStack removeAllObjects];
    self.operandStackIsEmpty = YES;
    self.operationIsPicked = NO;
}

- (void) pushOperand : (double) operand{
    [self.operandStack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
    self.operandStackIsEmpty = NO;
}

- (double) popOperand {
    NSNumber *num = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if (num) {[self.operandStack removeLastObject];}
    return [num doubleValue];
}

- (double) performOperation : (NSString *) operation{

    double result = 0;
    double num2 = [self popOperand];
    double num1 = [self popOperand];
    if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"])
        result = num2 + num1;
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"-"])
        result = num2 - num1;
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"*"] || [operation isEqualToString:@"x"])
        result = num2 * num1;
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]){
        if (num2 == 0)
            [self resetStack];
        else 
            result = num2 / num1;
    }

    [self pushOperand:result];
    self.operationIsPicked = NO;

    return result;

}

@end
```

Also, the debugging NSLog that I had print the display in the console works correctly, BUT the display in the Calculator view doesn't actually update (when I used breakpoints to slow the function down).

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"


@interface CalculatorViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;

@end


@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = _userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize display = _display;

- (CalculatorBrain *) brain {

    if (!_brain) {
        _brain =[[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    }
    return _brain;

}

- (IBAction) digitPressed: (UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber)
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString: digit];
    else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;
    }

}

- (IBAction) clearPressed {
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
    self.display.text = @"0";
    [self.brain resetStack];
}   


- (IBAction) equalsPressed {
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
    if (self.brain.operationIsPicked) {
        [self.brain pushOperand: [self.display.text doubleValue]]; 
        double result = [self.brain performOperation: self.brain.operation];
        self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%g", result];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.display.text);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",self.display.text);
}

- (IBAction) operationPressed:(UIButton *) sender {

    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) { 
        [self.brain pushOperand: [self.display.text doubleValue]]; 
        self.brain.operation = [sender currentTitle];
        self.brain.operationIsPicked = YES;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
        NSLog(@"%@", sender.currentTitle);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Post the whole error message. What's the unrecognized selector?

Comment: Are you using storyboards or a .xib?

Comment: How is your app working with IBActions that doesn't have a sender argument?

Comment: Never mind, all! I found the error! The full error said that I sent an invalid argument to "[self.brain equalsPressed:]". In reality, equalsPressed takes no argument, but when I was linking the '=' button in my view to its respective method, I forgot to indicate that the function took no arguments. Hence even though the function as I wrote it has no arguments, I told the compiler (to begin with) that it was supposed to take an argument. That's why the error points to errorPressed WITH a ':' afterwards. I fixed the error by making a new '=' button and making sure that no argument was selected.

Comment: Also, I was using storyboards, and theAmateurProgrammer came close to the source of the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the answer in the comments:

"The full error said that I sent an invalid argument to "[self.brain equalsPressed:]". In reality, equalsPressed takes no argument, but when I was linking the '=' button in my view to its respective method, I forgot to indicate that the function took no arguments. Hence even though the function as I wrote it has no arguments, I told the compiler (to begin with) that it was supposed to take an argument."